# Open file as ReadOnlySpan<byte> for SpanReader<byte>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm currently using DotNext's `SpanReader<byte>` to have a `BinaryReader` which works on `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

The goal is to have fast code with less allocations which replaces this part:

```cs
using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(emfFile)))
```

Current implementation:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> ros = File.ReadAllBytes(emfFile).AsSpan();
DotNext.Buffers.SpanReader<byte> spreader = new SpanReader<byte>(ros);
```

Is there anything which could be improved? I'm struggling to find another method which could replace `File.ReadAllBytes` as I guess this part could be improved (maybe read in chucks/buffers/...).

Comment: Approximately how big will the file be? I ask because these days the optimal chunk size (for modern SSDs) is larger than most files

Comment: few KB till few maybe 32MB+

Comment: You can easily get away with a simple `ReadAllBytes` then, unless that + is very significant.

Comment: Are you actually saving memory / allocations? When reading from a stream you would only need a fairly small, fixed sized buffer. If you are using a span you will have to read everything into memory, I don't really see where you would get the improvements from. Maybe you could memory map the file? But I'm not sure that will work with Span, or if it would be an overall improvement.

Comment: complete codebase has been rewritten using readonlyspans to reduce the allocations. Only the entrypoint (= loading the file) is where I was wondering if there were better alternatives instead of file.readallbytes. Some kind of File.OpenRead where I have a pointer to the beginning of the file and only consume what is needed (in some cases I don't need to read the complete file but just maybe half of it.

Comment: You could read into a pre-existing array, but you still need to allocate it, so if you're only doing this once then either way you're allocating one array. Memory-mapping the file initially avoids allocating an array (which does not mean that it's free of allocations, just that the stuff it allocates isn't an array object), but that doesn't give you a span, so you'd be back to creating an array and copying the data to it.